# How do I retrieve external data from MS SQL from a Wordpress Blog?

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

In Wordpress, how would I pull data from an external Microsoft SQL database to display as a read only table?

To be clear, this is not a question on how to convert Wordpress over to MS SQL, but rather how to pull data for a specific widget from a source outside the primary Wordpress DB. The data I need to pull from happens to be in a MS SQL database.

For the sake of example, let's say that I need to pull store locations and hours:

```
/* Retrieve store locations from the external MS SQL database*/

SELECT id, name, address, city, state, zip, phone, openingTime, closingTime
FROM locations
ORDER BY name
```

And display that data into a table on a Wordpress page:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Store Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Store Hours</th>
</tr>

<!-- Display rows of store locations here -->

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress runs on PHP and so you need to use a PHP provider for SQL Server. See [Accessing SQL Server Databases with PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(SQL.90).aspx).

If you host Wordpress on Linux, you need FreeTDS, see [PHP mssql Requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php).

Comment: Good resources! The Linux info is helpful for reference, but currently we're running Apache, PHP and Wordpress on a Windows server.

Comment: the link has plenty examples how to connect, execute a query, retrieve the result and iterate the result and format output html. Do you need help on that part, or can you take it from here?

Comment: No, that Microsoft page is quite helpful! I think its all I need, but I'm reviewing the page against my question before I select the answer and close the question.